# Maze solving with recursive backtracking algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, big-o, time-complexity

I have implemented [this](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/) recursive backtracking algorithm in C++ to create a maze solver program.

```
FIND-PATH(x, y)
if (x,y outside maze) return false
if (x,y is goal) return true
if (x,y not open) return false
mark x,y as part of solution path
if (FIND-PATH(North of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(East of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(South of x,y) == true) return true
if (FIND-PATH(West of x,y) == true) return true
unmark x,y as part of solution path
return false
```

**I am having trouble analyzing this algorithm's time complexity.**

Here's my implementation (*which I have simplified for the sake of this question, actual implementation uses some extra checks to determine which of the four directions to try first*):

```
bool Maze::FindPath(int x, int y)
{
    if (isOutsideMaze(x, y)) return false;

    if (maze[x][y].isBad) return false;

    if (x == goalX && y == goalY)
    {
        maze[x][y].isBad = false;
        return true;
    }

    if (maze[x][y].isBlocked)
    {
        maze[x][y].isBad = true;
        return false;
    }

    maze[x][y].isBad = true;

    if (FindPath(x, y + 1) == true) return true;
    if (FindPath(x - 1, y) == true) return true;
    if (FindPath(x + 1, y) == true) return true;
    if (FindPath(x, y - 1) == true) return true;

    maze[x][y].isBad = false;
    return false;
}
```

So, the question is, *what is time-complexity (big-O) of this algorithm in worst and average cases, **and** how do I calculate it*? I have tried looking for an explanation in other stackoverflow questions and on Google, but haven't found what I was looking for. Would appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

Is there a formal way to determine time-complexity of a recursive algorithm? Can the recurrence relation be used to calculate time-complexity?

Also, am I correct in assuming that recurrence relation of this algorithm would be something like `T(n) = 4T(n/4) + 1`?

**EDIT**

The worst-case would be where Start and Goal cell are maximum distance apart, and there are maximum number of 'open' cells in between the two. Something like the picture below. From what I have observed, the algorithm behaves as illustrated in the picture. Isn't this O(n)? If not, how do you explain that?
[image: Image depicting worst-case behaviour of the algorithm. Isn't it O(n)? If not, how do you explain that?]

Comment: Looks to me that it is brute force recursive search in all directions, and worst case should be `O(N^2)`. The reason I say that is if you consider instead of a maze, rather an open grid, it will search in all directions recursively until finally reaching the destination, but does no caching of grid cells it already looked in, nor is it an "informed" search (e.g. Dijkstra, A*, etc).

Comment: @CoryKramer: no, *O(2^N)*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My mistake, you are correct,

Comment: Can you explain how this is exponential? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @CoryKramer 'does no caching of grid cells it already looked in'
It marks already visited cells so that they are not visited from another direction, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @سیفخان: but you unmark them again after visiting.

Comment: Right! If I wanted to somehow be able to calculate its big-O formally, is there a way to do that? I need to be sure what you are saying is correct. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if you look at the algorithm again, you'd notice that a cell is unmarked only if there was no path leading away from that cell. In cases where a valid path is exists from current cell, the function **always returns before** unmarking the cell. Wouldn't that equate to '_caching of grid cells it already looked in_'? Since it would never look into a cell that was previously visited and hath leading away from it again.

Comment: @CoryKramer can you explain why this algorithm is exponential?

Comment: @سیفخان: yes, but it can fail, and this will create an exponential search tree.

Comment: It looks linear in number of cells to me.

Comment: @n.m. you mean O(n) where n=number of cells?